# Maori Macrons aren't recognized when converting the letter to PDF using aspose word

Tags: c#, symbols, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I'm using below code to convert html to pdf using aspose word plugin but the  Maori macrons aren't recognized and causing issue.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                    // load HTML file
                    Aspose.Words.LoadOptions loadOptions = new Aspose.Words.LoadOptions();
                    loadOptions.LoadFormat = LoadFormat.Html;

                    Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(stream, loadOptions);
                    foreach (Aspose.Words.Section section in doc)
                    {
                        section.PageSetup.PaperSize = PaperSize.Letter;
                        section.PageSetup.RightMargin = 20;
                        section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 10;
                        section.PageSetup.TopMargin = 10;
                        section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 10;
                    }
                    doc.Save(strPath, SaveFormat.Pdf);
```

Sample text before converting:

[image]

What we get in Pdf after conversion.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can make this a [mre] if you include a minimum HTML with accents. Also, the `PageSetup` stuff does not seem to be relevant here.

Comment: But it looks like a typical encoding issue. Try [LoadOptions.Encoding](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.loading/loadoptions/properties/encoding)

Comment: @saadsaf most likely the required font is not available on machine where conversion is performed. Aspose.Words requires fonts to be available when converting to Fixed Page Formats. Follow the link for more information:https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/using-truetype-fonts/ If the problem still persist, please post in Aspose.Words support forum https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8